# If-else statement checking first item in list always returns false?

Tags: prolog

I have written a method which takes user input from the console and turns it into a list. Afterwards it enters an if statement where it checks if the first element of the list (or first word entered) is 'A'. If so, print 'Yes' else print 'No.' So far I have only been able to get it to print 'No' despite the user input.

```
start :-
  read(String),
  string_to_list(List, String),
  (
    nth0(0,List,'A') ->
      writeln('Yes')
    ;
      writeln('No.')
  ).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be using `string_to_list/2` with swapped arguments. The first argument should be the string, and the second the list.
Then, to check if the first item is an `'A'` you should use the code for that letter, not the atom `'A'`, that is `0'A`.

```
start:-
  read(String),
  string_to_list(String, List),
  (
    nth0(0,List,0'A) ->
      writeln('Yes')
    ;
      writeln('No.')
  ).
```

Test:

```
?- start.
 |: 'ABC'.
 Yes
true.

?- start.
 |: 'BCA'.
 No.
true.
```